# Oracle Number mapping without precision - EF DB First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have a DB First ASP.NET MVC project, with Managed ODP.NET, and EF DB First . My Oracle tables have NUMBER columns, without precision, like NUMBER(3,6).

The EF maps these columns as DECIMAL, but I want to handle it with Int datatype.

How can I map Oracle Number with Int32 in EF DB First?

I followed these instructions, but I didn' succeed when I added the number type without precision.

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300

Comment: if you Need int, why not to define it as `number(10)`  and not as `number`. just `number` is always with precision

Comment: It's a another software's database and I don't have to right to modify it.

Comment: Well, then I guess you should live with `decimal`. Oracle `number` allows fractional numbers, hence it cannot be mapped to `int`.